# How to target an individual new input item in nested form using Cocoon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cocoon-gem

I am encountering a problem with rendering a collection of options in a nested field. The collection is dependent on a filled-in value in the existing form.

*I believe the fix will lie in targeting a new input field with an unique id for every new nested input field specifically, but please correct me if I'm wrong.*

**Context**

When rendering an order form, the program automatically builds a first field of 'order_options' (a table connecting orders and options, given its many-to-many relationship). The form provides a field to choose bike_type which has specific bike-type-related options. Based on the chosen bike_type, the form provides a picklist with the options. This part of my program renders correctly.

**My problem**

When adding another option via Cocoon's link_to_add_association, the user should again see the same picklist with options as the bike_type remains the same. Furthermore, the previously filled in option should stay (e.g. not be emptied again). However, in my current program

- the previously filled in code is deleted (because I need to empty the picklist in case the bike_type changes)
- the newly added nested form does not contain any options (I assume, but I am not sure, because it only uses the bike_type options for the first form field)

#### Form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@bike_store, @order] do |f|%>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_bikes do |order_bike| %>


      <%= order_bike.simple_fields_for :bikes do |bike| %>


        <%= bike.input :bike_type_id, collection: @bike_type_list, input_html:{
          value: @bike_type_list.object_id,
          id: "bike_type"
        }%>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.input :arrival %>
      <%= f.input :departure %>

      <%= order_bike.association :bike, collection: @bikes, input_html:{
        value: @bikes.object_id,
        id: "dynamic-bikes"
      } %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- test -->

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_options do |order_option| %>

      <%= render 'order_option_fields', f: order_option %>
  <% end %>

  <div>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :order_options, id:'add-option' %>
  </div>
  <!-- test -->

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### JavaScript/Ajax

```
<script>
  // Dynamic bikes
  $(document).on("change", "#bike_type", function(){
    var bike_type = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        // Dynamic bikes
        var bikes = response["bikes"];
        $("#dynamic-bikes").empty();

        $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option>Select bike</option>');
        for(var i=0; i< bikes.length; i++){
          $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option value="' + bikes[i]["id"] + '">' + bikes[i]["name"] + '</option>');
        }

        // Dynamic options after 1st build
        var options = response["options"];
        $("#dynamic-options").empty();

        $("#dynamic-options").append('<option></option>');
        for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
          $("#dynamic-options").append('<option value="' + options[i]["id"] + '">' + options[i]["name"] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // Test dynamic options for nested form
  $(document).on('click', '#add-option', function(){
    console.log('test')
    var bike_type = $('#bike_type').val();
    console.log(bike_type)

    $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var options = response["options"];
        // $("#dynamic-options").empty();

        $("#dynamic-options").append('<option></option>');
        for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
          $("#dynamic-options").append('<option value="' + options[i]["id"] + '">' + options[i]["name"] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

#### Nested form

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.association :option, collection: @options, input_html:{
        value: @options.object_id,
        id: "dynamic-options",
      } %>
</div>
```

#### Order controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @bike_store = Bike_store.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_bikes.build
    @order.order_options.build
    @bike_type_list = @bike_store.bike_types
    @bikes = []
    @options = []

    # Display bikes/options for type
    if params[:bike_type].present?
      @bikes = BikeType.find(params[:bike_type]).bikes
      @options = BikeType.find(params[:bike_type]).options
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {bikes: @bikes, options: @options}
      }
    end
  end

    authorize @order
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @bike_store = Bike_store.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order.bike_store = @bike_store
    authorize @order
    @order.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end


    private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:arrival, :departure,
      order_bikes_attributes: [:id, :bike_id, :bike_quantity, :_destroy,
        bikes_attributes: [:id,:name, :bike_type_id,
          bike_types_attributes: [:id, :name]]],
      order_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :option_quantity, :_destroy,
        options_attributes: [:id, :name, :bike_type_id, :description,
          bike_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]])
          # )
  end
end
```

The callback I tried as well:

```
  // Dynamic options for nest form
  $(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(){
    //$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(){
    console.log('test')
    var bike_type = $('#bike_type').val();
    console.log(bike_type)

    $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var options = response["options"];
        // $("#dynamic-options").empty();

        $("#dynamic-options").append('<option></option>');
        for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
          $("#dynamic-options").append('<option value="' + options[i]["id"] + '">' + options[i]["name"] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: From your question it seems when adding a new nested child (an option), it changes the form: so you are using a cocoon callback for this? Can you show this? The only code I now see is that you change _all_ `#dynamic_options` when the bike-type changes (regardless of whether a value was chosen or not). Please note: you are using html id's for repeating elements which will get you into trouble later on (you should be using classes). Also UI-wise: wouldn't it be better to just show all options, and the let the user mark (checkbox) the ones they want?

Comment: @nathanvda, thank you for the response. I tried using the cocoon:after-insert callback, but as this didn't work I deleted it again as decides to focus on targetting an individual new option instead. I edited the question with the attempt for a callback.

Comment: On the UI comment, you are right it would make sense to use checkboxes. The problem is that I cannot seem to find the resources to implement it, due to the many-to-many relationship and the option to select multiple. See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165753/how-to-add-dynamic-checkboxes-based-on-form-input).

Comment: You can select multiple, but each option only once, right?

Comment: I can render the options in the dropdown only the first time via the form that is built via the controller (``` @order.order_options.build```). Thereafter the drop-downs are empty.

Comment: If I imagine buying a bike or car, with a list of options, I can see all the options, and then use the checkbox to select which option I actually want. This could be pretty easy to implement, just list all the options, with a checkbox, and before saving you have to remove the unchecked ones, or only select the checked ones. A little bit easier, probably won't even need cocoon for that.

Comment: What does the `end` after `authorize @order` belong to? Why this particular indentation?

Comment: @nathanvda, you are right. I decided to figure out how to just list all options and assign a quantity to them. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Peter, I deleted part of my controller to limit the amount of code shown, I forgot to delete an end belonging to a different part of the code. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: You should still answer your own question, how did you solve it? It might be helpful for other people? Or delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing an object_id for all options belonging to the bike_type. Subsequently, I applied `'cocoon:after-insert'` on the `added option`.

Please find below the code for the solution.

_order_option_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields row">
          <div class="col col-sm-5"> <%= f.association :option, collection: @options, input_html:{
          value: @all_options.object_id,
          id: "dynamic-options"
          }%> </div>

  <div class="col col-sm-5"><%= f.input :option_quantity %></div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

script

```
<script >
    $(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_option_form){
      var bike_type = $("#bike_type").val();

      $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
      var options = response["options"];
      $(added_option_form.find("#dynamic-options")).html("");
      $(added_option_form.find("#dynamic-options")).empty();
       $(added_option_form.find("#dynamic-options")).append('<option>Select option</option>');
      // console.log(options.length);
      for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
        $(added_option_form.find("#dynamic-options")).append('<option value="' + options[i]["id"] + '">' + options[i]["name"] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
  });
```