# How to add dynamic checkboxes based on form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

**Context** 
A user can fill in an order form where a bike_type can be chosen and consequently the options belonging to that bike_type.

**Current situation**
Based on user input ('bike_type') in a simple_form column, I would like to include a checkbox with all potential options ('options) where multiple options can be selected. Currently, I am able to:

- (Situation 1) Display all the options for the respective bike_type via Ajax in the view, but unfortunately these are not being sent in the params.
- (Situation 2) Display **all options for all bikes**, these **are** inserted into the params and correctly saved, but this is not correct as users should only be able to select options that belong to the bike_type.

**HTML**
*I think the bug is in the JS inserting the options in the checkbox list. I tried mimicking the html shown below, but I cannot seem to get it right. Therefore, please find some printscreens of the HTML differences below.*

Incorrect html that is not inserted properly in the params below:

[image: Incorrect html that is not inserted]

Correct html that is inserted (As it renders all options incl. different bike options in the view) below:
[image: Incorrect html that is inserted but provides the wrong view]

form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@bike_store, @order] do |f|%>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, Option.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box", id='test-options'>
      <%= b.check_box %>
      <%= b.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

script

```
<script >
  $(document).on("change", "#bike_type", function(){
    var bike_type = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
    url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {bike_type: bike_type},
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);

      // test
      $("#test-options").html("");
      $("#test-options").append("");
      for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
        $("#test-options").append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + options[i]["id"] + '">' + options[i]["name"] + '');
      }
      // test

    }
  });
});
</script>
```

controller.rb

```
def new
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.new
    @orders = @bike_store.orders
    @order.order_options.build
    @options = []

    # Display options for bike_type
    if params[:bike_type].present?
      @options =  BikeType.find(params[:bike_type]).options
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {options: @options}
      }
    end
  end
    # test
    authorize @order
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order.bike_store = @bike_store
    @order.order_contact = @order_contact
    authorize @order
    @order.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

private
def set_order
    @order = order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:arrival, :departure, :order_contact_id,
      order_bikes_attributes: [:id, :bike_id, :bike_quantity, :_destroy,
        bikes_attributes: [:id,:name, :bike_type_id,
          bike_types_attributes: [:id, :name]]],
      order_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :option_quantity, :_destroy,
        options_attributes: [:id, :name, :bike_type_id, :description,
          bike_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only in rendering the proper input fields, then you may follow this approach:

This is a code snippet to render select options for events based on the user's age group..quite similar to yours:

```
.done(function (events){

                    var select = document.getElementById( "events-dropdown" );
                        while(select.length >0){
                            select.remove(select.length-1);
                        }
                        var option;
                    if( Object.keys( events ).length > 0){
                        events.forEach(function( event ) {
                                option = document.createElement( 'option' );
                                option.value = event.id;
                                option.textContent = event.title;
                                select.add( option );
                            });
                    }
                    // no events found for particular gender AND age group
                    else{ 
                        option = document.createElement( 'option' );
                        option.value ='';
                        option.textContent= 'Sorry! No events found for your age group';
                        option.disabled = true;
                        select.add( option );
                    }

                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe the ids should already be incorporated if the checkboxes are set up correctly (and consequently be correctly included in the parameters). Therefore, I think my mistake is likely to be in the handling of a many-to-many relationship between options and orders (via table order_options) and the option to select multiple options simultaneously.

Comment: Solved the many to many relationship via the collection_check_boxes feature. The bug is most probably in the JS now..

Comment: Solved it with collection_check_boxes using this article https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/